# how to find current request is ajax or not in mvc3 view javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

i have div with max height and overflow - auto, when div size overflows scroll bar added automatically, but i set

```
$("#itemsdiv").scrollTop(10000);
```

so that scroll bar is always at bottom .
Now i want that if view is load with ajax request then scrollbar is at bottom , 
and if view load when page refreshing then scroll bar will at top of div.
 can any one help me

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
 {
     <script>        
    //If Ajax Request Code Here
   $("#itemsdiv").scrollTop(10000);
   </script>
 }
 else
 {
    <script>//Else here
    $("#itemsdiv").scrollTop(10);
   </script>
 }
```

**Put the Above code in your View**

Comment: thank, it works well, actually i added same if loop but in script so that it doesnt work .